# Writing base64 image data toimage file using sails js

Tags: node.js, file, sails.js

In the current project I am working with  sails js as back end and angular js as front end. I have implemented a cropping module. By current problem is that, the output of the cropping module is base64 data. For doing some manipulations I need to convert this base 64 data to an image file. I received the base64 data at server side. Now need to convert this data to a file in sails js server side. I used a code for that, but not creating the image file. 
My sample base 64 data is below

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtWK6eAAAgAElEQVR4Xuy9B6wkeX4e9lVVd1Xn3P1yDpNz2J3N+e72juFODHfH......................."
```

my code for converting this base64 to image file is

```
var image = req.body.image.replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, "");
var filePath = 'imagecontents/';
fileName = filePath +'abc.jpg';

mkdirp(path.join(__dirname, '../../..' + filePath), function (err) {
                 if (err) {
                     logger.log('error', err);
                     res.sendStatus(500);
                     throw err;
                 }

require("fs").writeFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../..' + fileName), image, 'base64', function (err) {
                     if (err) {
                         logger.log('error', err);
                         res.sendStatus(500);
                         throw err;
                     }
                 });
```

Plz help to rectify is there is any error in in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the file using the below code:

```
var base64Data = data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
    require("fs").writeFile("out.png", base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
```